# Is it possible in GraphQL to define an xpath to ignore/skip a random field and extract inner object?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I'm newbie to GraphQL and I've a complicated json object in which I've a random field which I would like to ignore and get it's inner/next level object?

Suppose I've the following json returned by an external api that I'm trying to call and I would like to only extract list of `user` keys

```
{
  "users": {  
       "123321": { <!-- is a random number which can be any number -->
            "user": {
                "id": "123321",
                 "name": "Bob"
                 ...
             }   
       },
      "456654": {
           "user": {
               "id": "456654",
               "name": "Foo"
            }
      }
     ...
}
```

Ideally, when I define a query, I would like to extract and construct a map of all the `user` objects. If possible, can someone show me how this can be achieved, an example would be appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I’ve solved this is to convert that object into an array before handing it off to the resolvers:

```
const users = {
  users: [
    {
      id: "123321",
      name: "Bob",
    },
    {
      id: "456654",
      name: "Foo",
    }
  ]
};
```

This allows you to make direct queries:

```
query {
  user {
    id 
    name
  }
}
```

Basically, use JavaScript to change the data into the shape you need so GraphQL doesn’t need to do anything special.